# how to set a scene background?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scene

I've a scene with a UIWebView. The background color is white for a few seconds until the page is loaded. I need that white to be the color of the page. I know this last color, of course.

Comment: Where are you currently setting the color?

Comment: nowhere as I don't know where. I've tried the attribute inspector, the file inspector and the identity inspector and I cannot find where to set it.

Comment: In the attributes inspector, there is a background color property.